# In C++, gets() skips a line

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string str, char delimiter)
{
  vector<string> internal;
  stringstream ss(str);
  string tok;

  while(getline(ss, tok, delimiter))
  {
    internal.push_back(tok);
  }

  return internal;
}

int main() 
{
  freopen("in", "r", stdin);
  freopen("out", "w", stdout);
  int tt;
  scanf("%d", &tt);
  for (int qq = 1; qq <= tt; qq++) {
    printf("Case #%d: ", qq);

    char s[1234];

    stringstream ss;
    gets(s);
    for(int j = 0; s[j] ; j++) ss << s[j]; 

    vector<string> w = split(ss.str(), ' ');    
    for(int i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i)
    {
      printf("%s ", w[i].c_str());
    } 
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

Input

```
5

this is a test

foobar

all your base

class

pony along
```

---

Output

```
Case #1: 

Case #2: this is a test 

Case #3: foobar 

Case #4: all your base 

Case #5: class
```

---

I'm a C++ beginner. And I'm trying to solve reverse word problem: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p1

I couldn't figure out why my output gives this.

Please, help me.

Comment: Never include [bits/stdc++.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `scanf` eats the `5`, but not the newline following, so you end up consuming the remainder of the line as your first `getline` call (which, since the `5` was eaten, is an empty line).

Add a space after the format code in the `scanf` format string to make it consume the whitespace afterward, or to be safe, read the number by doing a `getline` and then parse it with `fscanf` or better, use a `stringstream` based parsing method to minimize mixing of `cstdio` and `iostream` functionality.

Comment: then adding  gets(s); outside the for loop will fix this problem.. thanks

Comment: @EunMin: It may, but really, as Sam says, you shouldn't be using the old, insecure C `stdio` functions at all, let alone mixing them with C++ `iostream` constructs. Stick to `getline` over `gets`, and use `stringstream` based parsing of each line rather than `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

`gets()` is not a C++ library function. It's a C function. Ditto for `freopen`(), and `scanf`().

Mixing C library `stdio` functions, and C++ Input/Output library function results in unspecified behavior.

Convert all of your code to use only `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::getline()` and other C++ Input/Output library functions.

Comment: Actually, in C++, `gets` does not even exist. See 27.9.2, table 134.